# How to overlay an image over a shortcode in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, image, overlay, shortcode

I'm trying to place an image over a shortcode (it's a slider's shortcode) but whatever html tricks I tried, either the slider would totally disappear or got smaller and placed at the side of the image.

When I use the absolute position to the shortcode the slider disappear:

```
<img class="alignnone" src="image" style="margin-bottom: -200px; margin-top: -100px;" id="__wp-temp-img-id" height="199" width="200" />
<h1 style="text-align: center; position: absolute;">[cycloneslider id="home-page-slider"]</h1>
```

Without the absolute position in the shortcode, the overlay image position BELOW the slider.

```
<img class="alignnone" src="image" style="margin-bottom: -200px; margin-top: -100px;" id="__wp-temp-img-id" height="199" width="200" />[cycloneslider id="home-page-slider"]
```

Any help is welcome.

Comment: Some code maybe? It's hard to go at it 'blindly'

Comment: @dingo_d when I use the absolute position to the shortcode the slider disappear.  <img class="alignnone" src="image" style="margin-bottom: -200px; margin-top: -100px;" id="__wp-temp-img-id" height="199" width="200" /><h1 style="text-align: center; position: absolute;">[cycloneslider id="home-page-slider"]</h1>Without the absolute position in the shortcode, the overlay image position BELOW the slider.
<img class="alignnone" src="image" style="margin-bottom: -200px; margin-top: -100px;" id="__wp-temp-img-id" height="199" width="200" />[cycloneslider id="home-page-slider"]